# Can't run PHP executable script. OS X 10.6

Tags: macos, script, php

*Execting php-scripts from the command line now does not work.* When executing a script starting with `#!/usr/bin/env php`. I get this error message:

> env: php: No such file or directory.

So it seems I can not run php as an executable script with `/usr/bin/php`.

I think what's causing my problem is that I followed [these instructions](http://auzigog.com/2009/05/10/setup-symfony-on-mac-os-x-using-mamp/) for allowing MAMP’s copy of PHP to run from the terminal.

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/php /usr/bin/php-old
```

appears not to be working. php is not renamed.

*If I should add something to my path. What should I add?* When running `echo $PATH`:

```
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin
```

*Btw (don't know if it is related)*: MySQL is running but I can't access http://localhost/ when running:

```
sudo apachectl start
```

Comment: What happens when you enter `which php`? Does it find your PHP installation? Does it work for every user account, or only for yours?

Comment: I did sudo mv /usr/bin/php-old /usr/bin/php. No I get /usr/bin/php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's why you should never mess around with `/usr/bin`, but keep local installations of binaries.

If you did the following

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/php /usr/bin/php-old
```

you will be able to revert by just doing

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/php-old /usr/bin/php
```

then `/usr/bin/env php` should work.

---

If you decide to continue with the MAMP installation, you can of course move your default `php` to `php-old`. But then you also need to execute the following *after* moving `php` to `php-old`:

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/bin/php /usr/bin/php
```

in order to have the `php` shipped with MAMP available under `/usr/bin/php`again.

But I can't promise that will work as expected **at all**. Again, you shouldn't move stuff in `/usr/bin`.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the path of your PHP installation directly in the script.

```
#!/Applications/wherever/it/is/you/installed/php
```